# layout collapsible doesnt work - primefaces

Tags: primefaces

i m working on a project. project main page has a layout with 2 layoutunits and each layoutunit have forms. when i run project page is loading correctly but one of layoutunit collapsible property does not work. when i click on it layoutunit is closing then opening again.

i m using primefaces 5.3 and i m not a elit user.

```
<p:layout fullPage="true" widgetVar="layoutWdgt">

    <p:layoutUnit  style=" font-size: 14px!important" position="west"   collapsible="true"  header="#{kullanici.adsoyadkullanici}" >

        <h:form id="anamenu">
            <p:panelMenu style="width: 250px; height: 600px!important">

                <p:submenu  label="Genel" icon="fa fa-cog">
                    <p:menuitem value="Ana Gösterge Tablosu 1" actionListener="#{turnPage.changePage(101)}" update="mainform:panel1" />
                    <p:menuitem value="Ana Gösterge Tablosu 2" actionListener="#{turnPage.changePage(102)}" update="mainform:panel1" />   
                </p:submenu>                        

                <p:submenu   label="Demografik Göstergeler" icon="fa fa-area-chart">

                    <p:menuitem value="Nüfus Piramidi" actionListener="#{turnPage.changePage(201)}" update="mainform:panel1" />
                    <p:menuitem value="Genel Demografik Göstergeler" actionListener="#{turnPage.changePage(202)}" update="mainform:panel1"/>
                    <p:menuitem value="Kırsal ve Kentsel Nüfus" actionListener="#{turnPage.changePage(203)}" update="mainform:panel1"/>
                    <p:menuitem value="0-14 Yaş Nüfus Oranları" actionListener="#{turnPage.changePage(204)}" update="mainform:panel1"/>
                    <p:menuitem value="65 Yaş Üstü Nüfus Oranları" actionListener="#{turnPage.changePage(205)}" update="mainform:panel1" />
                    <p:menuitem value="Toplam Yaş Bağımlılık Oranları" actionListener="#{turnPage.changePage(206)}" update="mainform:panel1" />

                </p:submenu>
                </p:panelMenu>
        </h:form>
                </p:layoutUnit>

            <p:layoutUnit id="layoutcenter" style="font-size: 14px"  position="center" collapsible="true"  >

                    <h:form id="mainform">

                        <p:outputPanel id="panel1">
                            <ui:include src="#{turnPage.pathpage}" />
                        </p:outputPanel>

                    </h:form> 
                </p:layoutUnit>
</p:layout>
</h:body>
```

Comment: Does it still fail if you remove the submenu? Or if you remove the include? Please try and if it still fails, edit the question and remove that code. If it does not fail, you have more info to post in your question.

Comment: it is working if i remove include.

Comment: i have solved. my included pages have to <ui:composition> tags. i added them then problem is solved, thx Kukeltje.

Comment: See the need/relevance to create an [mcve]. Next time remember that... !!!